# What does the T* written in orange refer to?

Tags: sony

One of the promo images of Sony's newly launched A7C shows "T*" written in orange on the side.
What does it mean?[image: Sony A7C promo image of left side of camera showing the letters "T*" in orange next close to the viewfinder]

Comment: [T* refers to a Zeiss lens coating](https://lenspire.zeiss.com/photo/en/article/technical-article-on-t-coating-and-reduction-of-reflections-in-lenses/) that reduces reflections. I know that some of the Sony lenses have T* coatings, but I'm not sure how that would apply to the camera body, unless it's in the viewfinder or sensor stack.

Comment: Yes, it relates to the EVF... [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FZW09bD0m4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FZW09bD0m4)

Answer (score 5):

T* refers to Zeiss T* anti-reflective coatings applied to the Electronic View Finders on Sony Cameras.  I believe it first appeared on the Sony A7R II in 2015.

[NEW SONY ALPHA A7R II](https://briansmith.com/field-test-sony-a7rii/)

> ***The EVF gets an update too with a new best-in-class 0.78x Tru-Finder that delivers a larger view than any cameras in the category. 1.0x magnification would be actual size of a 35mm frame. Previous a7-series cameras along with most fullframe optical viewfinders are around 0.70. That’s a much more visible improvement than the number of pixels. Zeiss T* coating have been added to an additional element for a sharper view especially at the edges – at least for eyeglass wearers like me.***
>
> ***In short, it’s Bigger and Clearer.***

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]